# How can I install pg gem on Debian for use on AWS beanstalk app?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

This one has appeared in numerous guises on stackoverflow but I still cannot get it to work, despite multiple searches and attempts. Basically I have done:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-client libpq5 libpq-dev
sudo gem install pg
```

and I have tried

```
bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/usr/lib/postgresql94/bin/pg_config
sudo gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/bin/pg_config
```

I still get the error message from the logs which says:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby1.9 extconf.rb 
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.
```

This is distressing me, has anybody managed to solve it? I am using debian jessie on my local machine.

Thanks as always.

Answer (score 0):

Configuring packages on Elastic Beanstalk instances as in .config file in a top level .ebextensions folder.

```
# .ebextensions/packages.config
 packages:
  yum:
  postgresql-devel: []
```

And redeploy the app.

For full steps, please look into this,

[AWS with Elastic Beanstalk app and pg gem](http://blog.juliantescher.com/how-to-set-up-a-rails-4-2-app-on-aws-with-elastic-beanstlk-and-postgresql)

Comment: no go sorry, exactly the same error message from aws logs

Comment: thanks trying. By "redeploy the app" do you mean just do a git push or "Rebuild Environment" on the aws console? Or something else?

Comment: I did a git push and also restarted the server, on the aw console, still get same error. I put the packages.config file in the .ebextensions folder.

Comment: have you configuring database.yml to work with RDS postgres and changes DB Engine to “postgres”  in AWS EBS?

Comment: I will do the whole thing again from the start and then tell you the result. I appreciate your help

Comment: I am using heroku for this at the moment (no pg gem issues), I will go back to AWS in due course and let you know if your solution works. Thank you for your input. Sorry for delay in validating your answer.